# Rasa installed but rasa_nlu.converters not found

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

**Rasa version: 0.14.6**

**Python version: 3.6.4**

**Operating system: osx**

**Issue:**

Running a snippet with this line :

```
from rasa_nlu.converters import load_data
```

Getting this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "nlu_model.py", line 1, in 
>   from rasa_nlu.converters import load_data ModuleNotFoundError: No
>   module named 'rasa_nlu.converters'

However, `pip freeze | grep rasa-nlu` returns

> rasa-nlu==0.14.6

Content of configuration file (config.yml):

```
language: "en"

pipeline: spacy_sklearn
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are following wrong documentation as you are using v0.14.6 the appropriate way to import load_data is :

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
```

Answer (score 0):

In rasa-nlu version 0.14.6 and newer versions the correct path is 
`rasa_nlu.convert`. 
Depending on what you are trying to do with the command this now would be something like:

`from rasa_nlu.convert import convert_training_data`,

`from rasa_nlu.convert import add_arguments` or

`from rasa_nlu.convert import main`

where main() is:

```
def main(args):
    convert_training_data(args.data_file,
                          args.out_file,
                          args.format,
                          args.language)
```